# Spring JPA, Eclipselink and Auditing

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink

I have been configuring Spring auditing for my entity classes.  Using annotations, I have something like this:

```
@CreatedDate
@NotNull
private Date createdDate

@CreatedBy
@NotNull
private User createdBy
```

The createdBy field is being set correctly, however persisting the object fails with a null createdDate. I am guessing that this may be related to type conversion for Eclipselink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Temporal annotation is available since the release of JPA 1.0. @Temporal solves the one of the major issue of converting the date and time values from Java object to compatible database type and retrieving back to the application.

`@Column(name = "XDATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATETIME) 
private Date xDate; //java.util.Date`

I hope this will resolve your problem. For more info please refer this [link](http://shengwangi.blogspot.in/2014/12/the-value-of-annotation-temporal-for-date-column.html)